# GSAP animate elements in an array fetched from the server

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, gsap

I would like to animate each element in an array with *TweenMax.staggerFrom*. At the moment I created this working sample

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect createRef } from 'react';
import { TweenMax } from 'gsap';

const AnimateView = () => {
  const data = [
    { title: 'Title 1', value: 1000 },
    { title: 'Title 2', value: 1100 },
    { title: 'Title 3', value: 1200 },
  ];

  const elementsRef = useRef(data.map(() => createRef()));

  useEffect(() => {
    const elements = elementsRef.current.map(el => el.current);

    TweenMax.staggerFrom(elements, 1, { scale: 0 }, 0.3);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {data.map((item, index) => (
        <div ref={elementsRef.current[index]}>{item.title}</div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};

export default AnimateView;
```

The difference is that I want **data** array to be fetched from the server. I cannot figure out why in **elementsRef** I'm getting no attached refs. Below you can check what I wanted to achieve.

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect createRef } from 'react';
import { TweenMax } from 'gsap';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchData } from 'actions';

const AnimateView = ({ combineFetching, income }) => {

  const elementsRef = useRef(income.length && income.map(() => createRef()));

  useEffect(() => {
    const elements = elementsRef.current.map(el => el.current);

    TweenMax.staggerFrom(elements, 1, { scale: 0 }, 0.3);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={fetchData}>Click</button>
      {income.map((item, index) => (
        <div ref={elementsRef.current[index]}>{item.title}</div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};

const mapDispatchToProps = state => ({
  income: state.budget.income,
});

export default connect(
  mapDispatchToProps,
  { fetchData },
)(AnimateView);
```

On Click I want to fetch data from database and animate each element in the array.